# Laravel 5.1 Force non-WWW and HTTPS Not Working

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to force https and non-www on my laravel site. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

#if the request is not secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#redirect to the secure version
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect to non-WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Here are the current redirects

**Working redirects**

```
example.com                  => https://example.com           (GOOD)
www.example.com              => https://example.com           (GOOD)
https://www.example.com      => https://example.com           (GOOD)
```

**Direct to the correct URL works fine**

```
https://example.com          => https://example.com           (GOOD)
https://example.com/asdf     => https://example.com/asdf      (GOOD)
```

**NOT Working redirects**

```
example.com/asdf             => https://example.com/index.php (BAD)
www.example.com/asdf         => https://example.com/index.php (BAD)
https://www.example.com/asdf => https://example.com/index.php (BAD)
```

I can't figure out why it's redirecting to the index.php file when I'm not on the main page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After 2 hours of searching for the solution it turned out to be extremely simple.

All I had to do was change the order of my .htaccess file to

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect to non-WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]

#if the request is not secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#redirect to the secure version
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```